# I have a Hibernate POJO which contains a "Boolean" field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Hibernate POJO which contains a `boolean` field, and if the object doesn't already exist (i.e. When a new one is created), then I want the `boolean` field value to default to `false`. How can I accomplish this using annotations?

Currently I have used:

```
@Column(name = "IS_DELETED",columnDefinition = "Boolean DEFAULT new Boolean(false)")
private Boolean isDeleted;

@Column(name = "IS_DELETED",columnDefinition = "Boolean DEFAULT false")  
private Boolean isDeleted;
```

I need to use this by default it storing null value....even following is also not working

```
@Column(name = "IS_DELETED",nullable=false,columnDefinition = "Boolean DEFAULT new Boolean(false)")  
private Boolean isDeleted;
```

Comment: How about `private Boolean isDeleted = false`?

Comment: What @AliDehghani suggested is the correct answer. You need to either set the default value in the Java code or in the database. There is no annotation to add a default value.

Comment: You can also look at `@PrePersist` annotation as a workaround too

Comment: `private Boolean isDeleted = false` or `public MyPojo() { setDeleted(false); }`.

Comment: thanks......but i was looking for using annotations.

Comment: @SatishSuradkar did you try the solution i proposed to you?

Comment: private Boolean isDeleted = false

Comment: @cralfaro i use this one

Comment: @SatishSuradkar if the response i give you was valid, please mark it as OK, so more people could use in a similar situation :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to use is

```
@Column(name = "IS_DELETED",columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 0")
private Boolean isDeleted;
```

But this value only will be "False" when you save into DB, so if you create an entity and check the value will be NULL, so I would recommend to use a default value as some people already said

```
@Column(name = "IS_DELETED",columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 0")
private Boolean isDeleted = Boolean.FALSE;
```

But in this case the columnDefinition wont make sense, never would be use...Is up to you to decide what is logically right with your business logic